# Is it guaranteed that socket descriptors in linux/freebsd will have almost sequential or comparable numbers?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I understand that there is nothing preventing linux to assign descriptors any random numbers in range 0...2^32 when I create new socket. **But what reality is?** In my application (web server) I need a mapping structure that maps descriptor into a "connection structure". I understand that some kind of RB-Tree (int -> connection_ptr*) will work, but linear array of connection_ptr pointers (where each pointer placed at offset (index) = descriptor value) would be a little faster.

Comment: You can use hashed container like `std::unordered_map` (maybe with custom hasher) to gain both space-efficency and very fast access.

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed

Comment: I know you asked about Linux but socket handles are pointers in Windows, not integers, so they are definitely not dense in the space, so any solution that assumes they are won't port.

Comment: @EJP: It depends on what implementation of the standard library you're using, but there's no way `select` can be provided if they're not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it were implemented that way, if you care for portability and reliability, you cannot rely on that.

To get almost constant access complexity, you can use a hashed container, like [`std:unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). You can even write a custom hasher, so the storage will be optimized for the file descriptor number distribution.

```
struct SocketHasher {
    size_t operator()(uint32_t key) {
        return key & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, connection_ptr, SocketHasher> connectionPool;
```

Comment: Why i need the custom hasher?

Comment: You can use it to distribute sockets among the map buckets better, if you know how the sockets # are generated. However that part is completely optional and my guess is that the code will perform well without it too.

Comment: This answer is wrong. File descriptors are defined such that they are assigned in a lowest-available manner. They are not abstract handles and you do not have to treat them as such. (Note: the public interface contract of `select` **requires** that you do numeric comparisons (a max operation) on file descriptors and does not function if all descriptors are not in a fixed range of 0 to `FD_SETSIZE-1`).

Answer (score 4):

File descriptors are always assigned from the lowest available number. This is guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: Is it process-wide or machine-wide though ? That is, if I have a few other applications running and creating/destroying sockets, I would expect to have (potentially large) gaps from the point of view of a single application.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Process-wide. File descriptors have no meaning outside of the process that created them.

Comment: Would be cool if a Windows-guy could weigh in and tell us, if it is the same over there.

Comment: @midor: My understanding that the answer is no for the pseudo-file-descriptor-like functions provided in MSVCRT, but of course yes if you're using a POSIX layer on Windows like Cygwin, Interix, etc.